# hibernate one to many annotation (mapping)error

Tags: hibernate

Here is my code below I would like to attain OnetoMany Hibernate Mapping in my company class and Person class 
code seems correct to me But there Is error in output while printing data 
So plzz if someone could help me out with this

**I would like to have One to many mapping from company class to multiple person and print all mapped data at once**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: Company, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(person)]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:336)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:310)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:241)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:496)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:270)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1358)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1849)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1928)
    at Rajat.Practice1.Main.main(Main.java:24)
```

Company class

```
package Rajat.Practice1;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.ElementCollection;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
public class Company {

    private int c_id;
    private String C_name;


    public List<Person> person = new ArrayList<Person>();

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="c_id")
    public int getC_id() {
        return c_id;
    }
    public void setC_id(int c_id) {
        this.c_id = c_id;
    }
    @Column(name="name")
    public String getC_name() {
        return C_name;
    }
    public void setC_name(String c_name) {
        C_name = c_name;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Company [c_id=" + c_id + ", C_name=" + C_name + ", person=" + person + "]";
    }
     public List<Person> getPerson() {
            return person;
        }
        @OneToMany(mappedBy="company", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)

        public void setPerson(List<Person> person) {
            this.person = person;
        }
    }
```

Person class

```
package Rajat.Practice1;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CollectionId;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Fetch;

@Entity
public class Person {


    private int Pid;

    private String name;

    public Company company;

    private PersonDetail p_detail;

    //@OneToOne ( cascade=javax.persistence.CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER  )
    //@JoinColumn(name="pdetail_pk")
    public PersonDetail getP_detail() {
        return p_detail;
    }
    public void setP_detail(PersonDetail p_detail) {
        this.p_detail = p_detail;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="Pid_pk")
    public int getPid() {
        return Pid;
    }
    public void setPid(int pid) {
        Pid = pid;
    }

    @Column(name="name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


   // @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
   // @JoinColumn(name="c_id")
    public Company getCompany() {
        return company;
    }

    public void setCompany(Company company) {
        this.company = company;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person [Pid=" + Pid + ", name=" + name + ", company=" + company + ", p_detail=" + p_detail + "]";
    }

}
```

Main Class

```
package Rajat.Practice1;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.imageio.spi.ServiceRegistry;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport;

public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

         Configuration cfg=new Configuration();  
            cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");  

            SessionFactory sf=cfg.buildSessionFactory();  
            Session session=sf.openSession();  
            Transaction tx=session.beginTransaction();  
            List <Person> lp=new ArrayList<Person>();
            PersonDetail pd=new  PersonDetail();
            pd.setCity("jaipur");
            pd.setState("jaipur");

            Person p=new Person();
            p.setName("Rajat");

            Person p1=new Person();
            p1.setName("Dynamo");


            Company c=new Company();
            c.setC_name("Protechgenie");


            p.setCompany(c);
            p1.setCompany(c);

        c.getPerson().add(p);
        c.getPerson().add(p1);


        lp.add(p);
        lp.add(p1);

        p.setP_detail(pd);

        session.save(c);
        session.save(p);
        session.save(p1);


        session.getTransaction().commit();
        Company com=(Company)session.get(Company.class, 1);
        Person per=(Person) session.get(Person.class, 1);
        System.out.println(com);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- In the `Company` class, you uncomment the mapping configuration
- In the `Person` class, the annotation (`@OneToMany(mappedBy="company", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)`) should be over the getter method.

Here is my code (note that I have deleted some of the unused properties)

```
@Entity
public class Company {

private int c_id;
private String C_name;

public List<Person2> person = new ArrayList<Person2>();

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="c_id")
public int getC_id() {
    return c_id;
}
public void setC_id(int c_id) {
    this.c_id = c_id;
}
@Column(name="name")
public String getC_name() {
    return C_name;
}
public void setC_name(String c_name) {
    C_name = c_name;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Company [c_id=" + c_id + ", C_name=" + C_name + ", person=" + person + "]";
}

@OneToMany(mappedBy="company", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
public List<Person2> getPerson() {
    return person;
}


public void setPerson(List<Person2> person) {
    this.person = person;
}
}

@Entity
public class Person2 {

private int Pid;

private String name;

public Company company;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="Pid_pk")
public int getPid() {
    return Pid;
}
public void setPid(int pid) {
    Pid = pid;
}

@Column(name="name")
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}


@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="c_id")
public Company getCompany() {
    return company;
}

public void setCompany(Company company) {
    this.company = company;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Person [Pid=" + Pid + ", name=" + name + ", company=" + company + "]";
}
```